# Proof of vector space properties using vector space axioms

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I have tried to prove the following:

"Let V be a vector space. For all $v\in V$ and all scalars $\alpha$. Prove that

a) $0v=\textbf{0}$

b) $\alpha \textbf{0}=\textbf{0}$

c) Prove: For every vector $v$ in a vector space $V$ is $-v=(-1)v$ and the vector $-v$ is unambiguously determined by $v$."

My approach:

a first approach) By distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to field addition we have
$$0v=(0+0)v=0v+0v.$$
There also exists an additive inverse $-0v$ of $0v$, such that $0v+(-0v)$ is the zero vector $0 \in V$. Then by adding $-0v$ to both sides of the above equality by associativity of addition and also the definition of the zero vector we get
$$0=(0v+0v)+(-0v)=0v+(0v+(-0v))=0v+0=0v$$
and thus, $0v=0$, as we desired.


a second approach) We have
$$0v=(0+0)v=0v+0v$$
We also have
$$0v=\textbf{0}+0v$$
Hence, by combing these we see that
$$0v+0v=\textbf{0}+0v$$
And by the cancellation law, we obtain $0v=\textbf{0}$


b) We have $\textbf{0}+\textbf{0}=\textbf{0}$ by axiom 3

Thus, we have
$$\alpha\textbf{0}=\alpha(\textbf{0}+\textbf{0})=\alpha\textbf{0}+\alpha\textbf{0}$$

We also have $$\alpha\textbf{0}=\textbf{0}+\alpha\textbf{0}$$
by axiom 3. If we combine these, we have
$$\alpha\textbf{0}+\alpha\textbf{0}=\textbf{0}+\alpha\textbf{0}$$
and the cancellation law yields $\alpha\textbf{0}=\textbf{0}$


c) We note that $(-1)v$ is the scalar product of $-1$ and $v$. On the other hand, $-v$ is the additive inverse of $v$, which is guaranteed to exist by axiom 4.

We show that $(-1)v$ is also the additive inverse of $v$

$$v +(-1)v=1v+(-1)v=(1+(-1))v=0v=\textbf{0}$$

So $(-1)v$ is the additive inverse of v. And because the additive inverse is unique, it follows that $(-1)v=-v$


My question is, are the proofs correctly done, and which of the approaches of a) is better, the first or the second approach?

Comment: They look fine, personally I'd go with the first

Comment: I think you've been asked to *prove* that the additive inverse is unique in a vector space.  Similar techniques to what you've already used will fill that gap.